# ruby проверка на корректность введеных данных ($)

Tags: ruby, валидация

Добрый день.
Я только начала изучать Руби и возник такой следующий вопрос.

```
puts "How much $ would you like to earn?"
    goal=gets.chomp.to_f
```

Как несложно  проверить, что пользователь ввел данные в формате `dd.cc` (d- доллар, с- центы) - 3.40 , 100,50 , 60.00 ?
А если пользователь ввел неправильно - чтобы вывело сообщение об ошибке.
Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Один из возможных вариантов - воспользоваться регулярным выражением. В этом случае введенную пользователем информации не следует сразу приводить к `Float`, сначала следует проверить, соответствует ли введенное значение заданному формату, а затем, приводить к `Float`

```
puts 'How much $ would you like to earn?'
goal = gets.chomp
puts 'Wrong pay format' unless goal =~ /\A\d{2}\.\d{2}\z/
puts goal.to_f
```

Comment: `raise 'Wrong pay format'`

Comment: @Nakilon да, можно так